# Why destructuring works differently than in classic assignation in Javascript (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

As you can see here we set "fibonacci" as an "iterable" object and we loop on it with a for .. of:

```
let fibonacci = {
              [Symbol.iterator]() { 
                let pre = 0, cur = 1;
                return {
                  next() {
                    [pre, cur] = [cur, pre + cur];
                    return { done: false, value: cur }
                  }
                }
              }
            }

            for (var n of fibonacci) {
              // truncate the sequence at 1000
              if (n > 1000)
                break;
              console.log(n);
            }
```

As expected in for of loop, console log write *1,2,3,5,8,..*

**BUT**

if I write `pre = cur; cur = pre + cur;` instead of `[pre, cur] = [cur, pre + cur];`

console.log will write *2,4,8,16,..*

**Why? Isn't destructuring just a way to set multiple values in a single line? How can we explain the difference in assignation?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
pre = cur; cur = pre + cur;
```

With the assignment to `pre`, you lost the old value of `pre` and the next assignment is wrong.

> ```
> pre  cur  comment           values
> ---  ---  ----------------  -------
>   0    1  start values         *
>   1    1  pre = cur
>   1    2  cur = pre + cur      *
>   2    2  pre = cur
>   2    4  cur = pre + cur      *
> ```

```
[pre, cur] = [cur, pre + cur];
```

The [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) keeps the values until the assignment of the whole array.

Comment: Finally, we can say that the destructuring helps assigning variables in the SAME time, avoiding rewriting of a value before the other one make use of this previous value. Javascript is a real beauty. Thanks Nina!